# How do I split an array inside an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that has a bunch of content separated by colons, so for example `initArray[0]` might have the content `10:30:20:10`. How do I split this again so I can have `initArray[0][1]`. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I tried a bunch of things but I couldn't get it to work at all. Javascript is not my forte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to split every element in the array:

```
for( var i = 0; i < initArray.length; i++ ) {
    initArray[i] = initArray[i].split( ':' );
}
```

So this:

```
[ '10:30:20:10', 'a:b:c:d' ]
```

becomes:

```
[ [ '10', '30', '20', '10' ], [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ] ]
```

Comment: oh god, I realised what I was doing wrong, I had the i and initArray.length the wrong way around in my for loop. I thought my syntax was flawed.

Answer (score 1):

```
initArray=new Array('10:30:20:10', '11:31:21:11');
for(i=0;i<initArray.length;i++)
{
    initArray[i]=initArray[i].split(':');
}
console.log(initArray[0][0]); // 10
console.log(initArray[1][0]); // 11​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tmp = "10:30:20:10".split(":")
alert(tmp[0]) ---> "10"
```